# Using AWS SES with international email addresses - RFC 2047

Tags: ruby, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I'm working on a product for Japanese clients and am getting an error when trying to send to email addresses like ああ@ああ.blah.jp AWS SES (simple email service) rejects the email address:
`Aws::SES::Errors::InvalidParameterValue (Local address contains control or whitespace)`

The SES docs say that you need to use RFC 2047 encoding which I am. ActionMailer encodes these addresses automatically so what gets sent to SES looks like:

```
=?UTF-8?Q?=E3=83=A6=E3=83=BC=E3=82=B6=E3=83=BC=E6=83=85=E5=A0=B1=E3=83=A6=E3=83=BC=E3=82=B6=E3=83=BC=E6=83=85=E5=A0=B1=E3=83=A6=E3=83=BC=E3=82=B6=E3=83=BC=E6=83=85=E5=A0=B1=E3=83=A6=E3=83=BCsfd=E3=82=B6=E3=83=BC=E6=83=85=E5=A0=B1@sdfds.com?=
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

Comment: You may have to [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) that domain.

Comment: The RFC 2047 spec says that you should be able to use UTF characters. Refer to https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/21222e1b48f08f6f848d26643d6b6fb1d873d18c/spec/mail/encodings_spec.rb#L733

Comment: _"ActionMailer doesn't seem to encode these addresses"_ – did you check that assumption?

Comment: Oops checked the logs and you're right it is being encoded. Don't understand why SES is rejecting it.

Comment: @jeznag That's typically in the email address component, not the domain component.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that user email contained whitespace the the end. So I removed the whitespace and it starts working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not supported by SES yet. Documentation is confusing on this topic.

Duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808009/does-amazon-ses-support-utf-8-email-addresses).